# Finding Grafana credentials when installed using prometheus-community operatorat prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, kube-prometheus-stack

I was trying to login to Grafana deployed using https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts using the credentials `admin:admin` but it was failing.

I found out the correct credentials to login to Grafana from the secret `grafana` which is `admin:prom-operator`
To see from where this value is getting injected to the secret I went to the template files and values.yaml files available at https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/grafana

The `secret` files is written as:

```
{{- if or (and (not .Values.admin.existingSecret) (not .Values.env.GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD__FILE) (not .Values.env.GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD) (not .Values.env.GF_SECURITY_DISABLE_INITIAL_ADMIN_CREATION)) (and .Values.ldap.enabled (not .Values.ldap.existingSecret)) }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ include "grafana.fullname" . }}
  namespace: {{ include "grafana.namespace" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "grafana.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
  {{- with .Values.annotations }}
  annotations:
    {{- toYaml . | nindent 4 }}
  {{- end }}
type: Opaque
data:
  {{- if and (not .Values.env.GF_SECURITY_DISABLE_INITIAL_ADMIN_CREATION) (not .Values.admin.existingSecret) (not .Values.env.GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD__FILE) (not .Values.env.GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD) }}
  admin-user: {{ .Values.adminUser | b64enc | quote }}
  {{- if .Values.adminPassword }}
  admin-password: {{ .Values.adminPassword | b64enc | quote }}
  {{- else }}
  admin-password: {{ include "grafana.password" . }}
  {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
  {{- if not .Values.ldap.existingSecret }}
  ldap-toml: {{ tpl .Values.ldap.config $ | b64enc | quote }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

and part of the `values.yaml` file is written as

```
# Administrator credentials when not using an existing secret (see below)
adminUser: admin
# adminPassword: strongpassword

# Use an existing secret for the admin user.
admin:
  ## Name of the secret. Can be templated.
  existingSecret: ""
  userKey: admin-user
  passwordKey: admin-password
```

and the `_helpers.tml` contains

```
{{/*
Looks if there's an existing secret and reuse its password. If not it generates
new password and use it.
*/}}
{{- define "grafana.password" -}}
{{- $secret := (lookup "v1" "Secret" (include "grafana.namespace" .) (include "grafana.fullname" .) ) }}
{{- if $secret }}
{{- index $secret "data" "admin-password" }}
{{- else }}
{{- (randAlphaNum 40) | b64enc | quote }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

which looks to me like the `admin-password` value is coming from the secret as it's not a random alphanumeric. This seems like a loop to me. Could you please explain to me how the default password value `prom-operator` is getting injected to the secret in the key `admin-password`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**: Value is set in `kube-prometheus-stack` values as `grafana.adminPassword` and passed to grafana subchart

`kube-prometheus-stack` uses the the `grafana` chart as a depencency, so you have to take a look at both those values.yaml files.

In `kube-prometheus-stack`, there's a value for `grafana.adminPassword` set per default:

https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/b8b561eca1df7d70f0cc1e19e831ad58cb8c37f0/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml#L877

This is passed down to `grafana` where it's referenced as `.Values.adminPassword` (see https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/#overriding-values-from-a-parent-chart)

The `grafana` chart prefers this value over generating a random password with the helper block you listed. As it is passed from the parent chart `kube-prometheus-stack` and not empty, this value is used.

```yaml
  {{- if .Values.adminPassword }}
  admin-password: {{ .Values.adminPassword | b64enc | quote }}
  {{- else }}
  admin-password: {{ include "grafana.password" . }}
  {{- end }}
```

https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/de3a51251f5b4fdd93715ba47d0065b282761a79/charts/grafana/templates/secret.yaml#L17-L21

Comment: Thank you for the input. I'm able to understand now.